# What's the best way to `take_last(n)` a non-sized range?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, range-v3

[Godbolt:](https://godbolt.org/z/oehjoWxEq)

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

namespace views3 = ranges::views;

int main()
{
    std::string_view sv = "Hello world! Goodbye world!";
    auto notBang = [](char ch) { return ch != '!'; };
    auto input = std::views::take_while(sv, notBang);
    static_assert(!std::ranges::sized_range<decltype(input)>);
    static_assert(!std::ranges::common_range<decltype(input)>);
    static_assert(std::ranges::contiguous_range<decltype(input)>);

    auto v1 = input | views3::take_last(3);  // ERROR
    std::cout << (v1 | ranges::to<std::string>) << "\n";  // rld

    auto v2 = input | views3::drop_last(3);  // OK
    std::cout << (v2 | ranges::to<std::string>) << "\n";  // Hello wo
}
```

Here `input` is a contiguous, non-common, non-sized range. range-v3's `take_last(n)` doesn't work on such ranges, because its strategy is simply to compute `ranges::begin(input) + (ranges::size(input) - n)` on construction, and non-sized ranges have no `ranges::size`.

But `drop_last(n)` *does* work on non-sized ranges, because *its* strategy is to keep two iterators `n` elements apart and advance them in tandem. The range between `drop_last`'s two iterators [EDIT: after it's been iterated] is exactly `take_last(n)` — but we can't get at it.

What's the simplest (and not-crazy-inefficient) way to get the last `n` elements of a non-sized range, using C++20, C++23, and/or Range-v3 facilities?

(Looking at the difference in complexity between Range-v3's 66-line [`take_last`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/a6cc9f9/include/range/v3/view/take_last.hpp) and 373-line [`drop_last`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/a6cc9f9/include/range/v3/view/drop_last.hpp), I suspect this might just be a temporary deficiency in Range-v3's `take_last`. Neither of them has been touched in 3 years, though...)

Comment: *'Looking at the difference in complexity between Range-v3's 66-line `take_last`...'* -- This is a terrible way to compare them, especially since `take_last` was defined [in terms of `drop_exactly`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/a6cc9f9c84d5e2b364202464c63ee7f5c14574e8/include/range/v3/view/take_last.hpp#L42).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `views::counted` to convert the origin range into a `sized_range` (But in the worst case you need to pay O(n) time complexity to calculate the actual size of the `input`)

```
auto v1 = views3::counted(input.begin(), std::ranges::distance(input))
        | views3::take_last(3);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f49abh5oj)

Comment: Neat, upvoted and will probably accept. Is there a known/proposed shorter spelling for `std::views::counted(r, std::ranges::distance(r))`? Feels like there ought to be a `views::make_sized(r)` (or some such bikesheddable spelling) in the same way as there's a `views::common(r)`. I see it can also be spelled using `subrange`, but haven't gotten anything simpler than this: https://godbolt.org/z/oKb81jK1c

Comment: @Quuxplusone You can just write `ranges::subrange(r, ranges::distance(r))`. But that's also now really the same thing as what you'd want from `views::make_sized(r)` since it's not actually holding onto `views::all(r)`.

Answer (score 4):

> Looking at the difference in complexity between Range-v3's 66-line take_last and 373-line drop_last, I suspect this might just be a temporary deficiency in Range-v3's take_last. Neither of them has been touched in 3 years, though...

This is because `drop_last` supports forward-but-not-sized ranges and `take_last` only supports sized.

You *could* implement a `take_last` to work on forward-but-not-sized as well, following the same logic that that the `drop_last` implementation uses: have another iterator to "probe" where the end is.

Which would basically be something like this:

```cpp
template <forward_range V> requires view<V>
struct take_last_view {
    V base;
    int n;

    // only necessary if not (sized + random access)
    optional<iterator_t<V>> cached_begin;
    

    auto begin() -> iterator_t<V> {
        if constexpr (random_access_range<V> and sized_range<V>) {
            auto s = ranges::size(base);
            if (s <= n) {
                // if I want to take the last 5 out of 3 elements, that's all 3
                return ranges::begin(base);
            } else {
                return ranges::begin(base) + (s - n);
            }
        } else {
            if (not cached_begin) {
                auto it = ranges::begin(base);
                auto probe = ranges::next(it, n, ranges::end(base));
                while (probe != ranges::end(base)) {
                    ++it;
                    ++probe;
                }
                cached_begin.emplace(it);
            }
            return *cached_begin;
        }
    }

    auto end() -> sentinel_t<V> {
        return ranges::end(base);
    }
};
```

Ideally `cached_begin` is actually a conditional member, since you only need it in some cases. But otherwise, this is a viable range adaptor.

You can see an example implementation of this [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bG36qq6a7), which looks like it does the right thing. It's not a complete implementation (things missing include: this could support an input+sized range, this should be sized if the underlying range is sized, const-iterable if the underlying range is const-iterable, etc.).

Comment: Any chance of this version ever arriving in range-v3 or in std::ranges? Would you agree with Nicol Bolas that this version of `take_last` is _more_ philosophically problematic than the existing `filter_view`? and would you say that's a blocker w.r.t. standardizing it? (Feb 2022's [P2214r2 "A Plan for C++23 Ranges"](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2214r2.html) lists no active papers yet for Tier 2, the tier containing `take_last`, so maybe the design space is still open?)

Answer (score 1):

> The range between `drop_last`'s two iterators is exactly `take_last(n)`

No, it's not. `drop_last`'s two iterators start with `begin()` and `begin()+n`. `take_last`'s range is from `end() - n` to `end()`. These are not the same range.

`drop_last` works because it doesn't initially have to figure out where `end() - n` is. It discovers this naturally as you iterate through the range. `take_last` must *start with* `end() - n`. Therefore, it must compute it. And to compute it, it also must determine if `end() - begin()` is less than `n`, so that it can cap the starting iterator at `begin()`.

And it can only do that computation in constant time if the range has a size compute-able in constant time. IE: it is sized.

There's no getting around this. If you want `take_last` to be constant-time, it must be given a range whose size can be computed in constant-time. If you're willing to suffer an O(n) operation (where "n" is the size of the range), you can work around this. But I would not consider that an "efficient" solution.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "The range between `drop_last`'s two iterators _when you're done iterating it_ is exactly `take_last(n)`." Obviously it takes `size(r)-n` time to iterate over `drop_last`, and then `n` more time to iterate over the `take_last` range. I see how this relates to the "ranges must be O(1) constructible" debate. But consider that even `drop_last(n)` requires `O(n)` time to construct! (Not `O(size(r))` time, but still, `O(n)` time where `n` is user-provided.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone: But that's a different thing. `drop_last` is constant-time constructible relative to the size of the range. That's what matters. That is, feeding in a bigger range doesn't change its time complexity.

Comment: @NicolBolas I believe they both need to buffer `n` item internally, I don't see specific reason `take_last` cannot be *construct* in `O(n)`

Comment: @appleapple: You're misusing `O(n)` here. The `n` in that statement was the total size of the range, not the number of elements you're taking.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes I mean it can be construct in `O(n)`, i.e. non-dependent to input range.

Comment: @appleapple: But that's not the `n` I am talking about. That's not the `n` that actually matters for performance. And its certainly not the `n` that's going to decide whether it is an efficient operation or not. For a non-sized range, you cannot compute the start of a `take_last` range in constant time relative to the size of the given range.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't really understand. My guess would be the begin then cannot be dereference in `O(1)` is the problem.

Comment: We should take the discussion to [Slack](https://cppalliance.org/slack) or something at this point, but what I mean is I forget how the `take_last` situation is really any different from the `views::filter` situation. You cannot both create-and-get-the-first-item of a `filter_view` in O(1) time either, _if_ the first item matching the filter is all the way at the end of the input range. I don't currently see why `take_last` should be philosophically different from `filter`. (And admit of the same hacky fixes if needed, e.g. caching its begin iterator.) But, let's not discuss in comments.

Comment: @Quuxplusone: The difference is that you cannot do constant-time `begin` for *any* `views::filter` range. There is no inherent property of the range that would allow that. You can only do amortized constant-time. You *can* do constant time for sized `take_last` ranges.